# How to objectively decide when the value is stable?

Tags: r, machine-learning, modeling, geostatistics

Let's say that I've build models using three different values of some parameter (for example Max Tree Depth) in 1500 iterations. Right now, I want to decide after how many iterations the accuracy value stabilize. Visually, I could say that the accuracy stabilize at about 150-200 iteration. But, it's only my opinion. Is there any method to objectively decide when the value is stable?

[image]

Comment: A good place to start would be to have an objective definition of stability (perhaps https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stability_%28probability%29), although it might be more useful looking at whether you have reached a local maximum.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with using the graph as a heuristic decision regarding stability. There are clear changepoints in the shape.

Answer (score 0):

I would see your question as "after which iteration the data points can be modeled/fitted by an equation of the form `Accuracy = a` (constant)?". That means starting from iteration 1 and fitting an equation of the form `Accuracy = a + b*Iterations` until you find that `b` is not statistically significantly different than 0.

To be more specific:

1) Start from iteration 1 : Get all data

2) Fit a linear model `Accuracy = a + b*Iterations`

3) Is `b` coefficient statistically different from zero? (Yes/No)

4) If no you stop, if yes start from iteration 2 (all data apart from 1st data point) and continue as above.

Does it sound reasonable? Let me know if you have any questions and I'll update my answer.